# Joining and filtering two sets of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I guess this is an easy and stupid question, but considering this mysql "purchase" table (where p_id is auto-incremented):

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|   p_id  |    item_id  |  user_id      | count   | ... 
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|       1 | 4           |             1 |       22|
|       2 | 4           |             2 |        1|
|       3 | 1           |             1 |        1|
|       4 | 0           |             3 |        1|
|       5 | 3           |             1 |      182|
|       6 | 0           |             4 |        1|
|       7 | 3           |             2 |        7|
|       8 | 3           |             2 |       14|
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

What's an appropriate way (query) to get the rows where the users whose ids are 1 and 2 have purchased the same items, and only retrieved their last purchase of those items ?
The result should be something like this :

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|    p_id |    item_id  |  user_id      | count   | ... 
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|       1 | 4           |             1 |       22|
|       2 | 4           |             2 |        1|
|       5 | 3           |             1 |      182|
|       8 | 3           |             2 |       14|
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT p.p_id,p.item_id,p.user_id,p.`count`
FROM purchase p,
   (SELECT MAX(P1.p_id)as p_id,item_id,user_id
    FROM purchase P1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM purchase P2
                  WHERE P2.item_id = P1.item_id
                  AND P2.user_id <> P1.user_id
                  AND P2.user_id IN (1,2))
    AND P1.user_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY item_id,user_id)as result
WHERE result.p_id = p.p_id
ORDER BY p.p_id;
```

result

```
1|4|1|22
2|4|2|1
5|3|1|182
8|3|2|14
```

Comment: Yeh sqlFiddle site just went up again. here's the [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/284fab/1/0)